# Uri images not showing on android device (Xamarin)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, cross-platform

I'm trying to show an image using a ImageCell, it works fine on UWP but it does not appear when i debug using my android device

Some solutions suggested to change the HttpClient implementation to Managed and SSL/TLS implementation to Native TLS 1.2+ and i did but it didn't work!

I also tried to reduce size to 10 * 10 as one solution suggested and it also didn't work

Another solution said that the problem is something related to a byte[] and its only an android issue, but how do i alter this??

so i have a class Contact

```
public class Contact : ContentPage
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Status { get; set; }

        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the code behind

```
public Demo ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();

            listView.ItemsSource = new List<Contact>
            {
                new Contact {Name = "Khaled", ImageUrl="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/1"},
                new Contact {Name = "Mohammed", ImageUrl="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/2", Status = "Hey, lets talk"}
            };
        }
```

and this is the xaml code

```
<ListView x:Name="listView">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ImageCell Text="{Binding Name}" Detail="{Binding Status}" ImageSource="{Binding ImageUrl}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: Does your Android app have Internet permissions?  Have you looked at the application output log to see if any messages regarding images are displayed?

Comment: @Jason Thanks alot man! i added the internet permission to the androidManifest.xml and it works now (Y) Im very new this so it didn't even cross my mind! Thank again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it! All i had to do was to add internet permissions to the androidManifest.xml in properties in the android project like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

and now it works just fine